# Magento2: Bypassing an positive discount validation in file vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/AbstractModel.php

Tags: php, magento2

The detailed explanation is here, I can explain more if still not clear.

I'm trying to accomplish a positive discount thing in Magento 2,

Here is the example please try to add this product to cart, https://demostore.work/Designer/custom-bar-mitzvah-bencher-75
You can select "111" in option "**Test**" and "No, thank you" in option "**Personalize the Bencher**"

In totals on cart page, you will see the discount positive like highlighted in this screenshot
http://prntscr.com/lzbwy0

Till here all is working fine, the problem is on the checkout page.
After entering billing and shipping address when I try to place the order. I am getting this exception error message
http://prntscr.com/lzbxjr

This exception is coming from a Core file

> vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/AbstractModel.php

```
public function beforeSave()

    if ((int)$this->getDiscountAmount() < 0) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please choose a valid discount amount.'));
    }
```

If I comment this exception in core file everything works very well, but I don't want to edit the core file. I tried to create a preference but it is not working. Need help!

Comment: I don't see logic behind positive discount, if you are trying to charge customer then you can apply surcharge.

Comment: Hi @Kamal,
Thank you for replying I have fixed the problem. Now it is working as per need.
Regarding your query, I am using a positive discount to add surcharge because we can add conditions and it works great.